# Design a report with OO in Java

Tags: java, oop

I want to implement 2 reports with OO. The reports are all like (but have different columns and data):

```
name age gender phone_number
A    10  male   1234
B    20  female 5678
C    30  n/a    9012
```

As you can see, in the report, each column has its own header and parser (for parsing the data). I have design an object Column:

```
class Column<T extends Object>
{
    private String header;
    private ColumnParser parser;

    public Column(String header)
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.parser = new ColumnParser<T>()
        {
            public String parse(T t)
            {
                return t.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    public Column(String header, ColumnParser parser)
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public interface ColumnParser<T>
    {
        public String parse(T t);
    }
}
```

So that each column has its own parser to parse the data in that column. But after this, I don't know how to store the data so that they can be mapped to each column and can be parsed.

Please advise.

Comment: whats the role of DB in your code ?

Comment: Nothing with DB. All the data will be only in memory and will be output into files. The data comes from other file or service call.

Comment: I just want it has good extensibility so that it is easy to add new columns or create another new report.

Comment: First use `org.apache.poi` to dump data in report XLS format instead of text file.

Comment: The format has been decided like the example. I just want to design a generator with OO to make it easier to use and extended.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be helpful to know what format your original data (in memory) is in - e.g. is it an Object[][]?

Second, the output you require looks like it's tab separated. Is that correct?

Third, to write to a text file you have to append row by row. Your current code seems to suggest you want to append column by column - this would be much harder to implement.

If you can convert your data into a String[][] - which should be straightforward - you can then use the following to write to a file. If you want tab-delimited, you can use the "\t" as the delimiter (although, that's for windows - not sure if it is OS specific like new line).

```
public static void writeToFile(File file, String[][] data, String delimiter){
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
  for (String[] row : data){
    out.write(makeLine(row, delimiter));
  }
  out.close();
}

private static String makeLine(String[] row, String delimiter) {
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  for (String cell : row){
    str.append("\""+cell+"\"").append(delimiter);
  }
  str.deleteCharAt(str.length()-1);
  str.append("\n");
  return str.toString();
}
```